# Arithmetic Series worded question

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The sum of integers from $1$ to $p-1$ is equal to the sum of integers from $p+1$ to $49$. Find the value of $p$

I'm not sure if the value of $d$ and $n$ are the same where:

$n =$ the number of terms

$a =$ the first term.

I've spent a few hours trying to answer this question but can't work it out. Please help

Comment: It is really difficult to understand your question. Please, provide clearer information. Moreover, what have you tried so far? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: **Hint**: Find the sum $1+2+\dots+(p-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i$, and then find $(p+1)+(p+2)+\dots+49=(1+2+\dots+49)-(1+2+\dots+p)$

Comment: The answer to this question for the value of $p$ according to the book is 35.

Comment: Does $n$ and $d$ play any role in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\right\}$
has $p-1$ terms, the first is $1$ and the last is $p-1$, so
$$1+2+\ldots+(p-1)=\frac{(p-1)p}{2}$$
The other set has $49-p$ terms, then
$$(p+1)+(p+2)+\ldots+49=\frac{(49-p)(p+1+49)}{2}=\frac{(49-p)(p+50)}2$$
So, we have
$$\frac{(p-1)p}2=\frac{(49-p)(p+50)}2\quad\iff\quad p^2-p=2450-p-p^2\quad\iff \quad2p^2=2450$$
Then $$p^2=1225\quad\implies\quad \boxed{\color{red}{p=35}}$$

Comment: does this assume that $n$ and $d$ are the same?

Comment: @zam The common difference $d$ is constant in an arithmetic sequence. We are also told that the sum of the first $p - 1$ terms is equal to the sum of the last $49 - p$ terms.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n+\sum_{p+1}^{49}n=(\sum_{n=1}^{49}n)-p$$
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n=(\sum_{n=1}^{49}n)-p$$
Using Gauss formula $\sum_{j=1}^{n}j=\frac {n(n+1)}2$

$${(p-1)p}+p=\sum_{n=1}^{49}n$$
$$p^2=\sum_{n=1}^{49}n=\frac {n(n+1)}2 \big|_{n=49}=25 \times 49= (7 \times 5)^2$$
Therefore 
$$p=35$$